# netbeans 6.8 and zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I installed Netbeans 6.8 but in the PHP framework list it does not show Zend framework.  Do I need to configure it?  How do I do that?

Same this one : http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/zend_framework_support_added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be in the next release (AFAIK 6.9 is planned at the beginning of the summer). You can already download (or compile by yourself) dev build and try it out.

For now, ZF support in Netbeans it is just a wrapper for command line `Zend
_Tool`. You just configure your `zf.bat` path and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great plugin named "Path Tools" (get it from the netbeans plugins page). This will allow you to open a command window in your project directory. Then, creating a new project is really easy(ofcourse, you need to have zf.bat and php.exe in your path). Simply open command window..

> . zf create project
>
> . (you will be prompted for directory.. enter '.' for current dir)

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans does not create ZF projects. So first you need to create ZF project yourself using Zend_Tool, and than in NetBeans create New Project (File->New Project) and select PHP category with 'PHP Application with Existing Sources' and off course point to your newly created ZF project.

Comment: i like config same this http://blogs.sun.com/netbeansphp/entry/zend_framework_support_added

Comment: @ulduz114 It looks as this future is still under development. So maybe in next NetBeans release it will be included, though I'm not sure.